# Suse root group not having root rights?

Tags: sudo, root, suse

I am in the root group of a suse machine but when I use

```
sudo -u <myAccount> ...
```

I get a

```
Root privileges are required for...
```

a few terminal commands:

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers:
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL
root = ALL(ALL) ALL

$grep root /etc/group:
root:x:0:<myAccount>

$ grep x:0 /etc/passwd:
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

$ getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups    
<myAccount> : users root
```

I don't know, am I missing something? I can't use the "real" root password as I am not privileged here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK sudoers usually belong to the 'wheel' group.

I think adding you user to the 'wheel' group with

```
gpasswd -a $username wheel
```

and adding either

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

or

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to your /etc/sudoers file, depending on wheter or not you want password authentication for sudo, should solve your problem.

IF you want the 'root' group to have sudo previliges, I think you should add

```
%root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

notice the '%' prefix for groups.

Comment: Nice, the %root command worked for me. I still had the admin edit this with his root account but it works now like I wanted to. Thanks =)